# Generate the cumulative index within a nested *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a nested list of objects which I am iterating over, each object has an array inside.

```
arr: any[] = [
    { 'title': 'fruits', res: ['apple', 'pear'] }, 
    { 'title': 'numbers', res: [3, 5, 7, 11] },
    { 'title': 'letters', res: ['a', 'b'] }];
];`
```

I wish to iterate over each nested array `res` and output the cumulative index so that the output of the above equals this:

```
fruits
0 - apple
1 - pear

numbers
2 - 3
3 - 5
4 - 7
5 - 11

letters
6 - a
7 - b
```

Angular exposes the local variable `index`, but is there a way to define other local variables and increment them as we go along. Something like the below (*I know this doesn't render*)

```
<div *ngFor="let list of comboList; let i = index; let count = 0">
    <h1>{{ list.title}}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let item of list.res; let j = index; count ++">
        {{ count }} - {{ item }}
    </div>
</div>
```

So far my only working option is a function which gets called each time I want to display an item, which isn't very efficient.

```
getCumIndex(arr: any[], x: number, y: number){
    let count: number = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (x == i){
            return count + y;
        } else {
            count += arr[i].res.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be just better to make a new array which only elements from `res` key? And then use `*ngFor` on it.

Comment: This is a simplified version of my use case. Each object is returned from a separate service asynchronously, and the output isn't as simple as printing one line per item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o6CJLxzhMt7hbNwAxz0W?p=preview) for solution with custom pipe and helper class

```
<div *ngFor="let counter of [comboList | counterPipe]">
  {{ counter.reset() }}
  <div *ngFor="let list of comboList">
    <h1>{{ list.title }}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let item of list.res">
      {{ counter.inc() }} - {{ item }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this, what's the advantage to using a `WeakMap` in the counter?

Comment: If all references to the key of WeakMap are lost and there are no more references to the value - the value can be garbage collected. So, you don't need to remove items from it.

Comment: Understood, but what's the advantage of using the `WeakMap` aproach, versus something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/ksh71XsU75hqCKuVjONS?p=preview

Comment: No advantages, your version is better and should be used instead of `WeakMap`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward solution.
Here's your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let list of comboList; let i = index;">
    <h1>{{ list.title}}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let item of list.res; let j = index;">
       {{ cumulativeLength(i) + j }} - {{ item }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
cumulativeLength(index) {
    let acc = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i<index; i++) {
        acc += this.comboList[i].res.length;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

I haven't checked but it should work.

Comment: That is an almost identical solution to what I already have, as mentioned in the question

Comment: @ChristopherMoore you can count the length of res arrays once you have  loaded them, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Any custom logic except the angular pre-defined ng-attributes should be done in your component and not in your view.