# how to make assigned id not change with data binding in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to make the dynamic ids like canvas1, canvas2, canvas3, etc. Here i binded id with {{cc}}

```
<canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas{{cc}}" class="canvas-size"></canvas>
```

```
public cc = 1 ;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('AfterViewInit', this.cc);
    for (var i in this.testing) {
      console.log("cc",this.cc);
      this.chart = new Chart('canvas'+ this.cc, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          labels: ['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4'],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: [25, 50, 20, 5],
              backgroundColor: ['#2D5E9E', '#46AACE', '#DCECC9', '#f7f9fa']
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          tooltips: {
            enabled: false
          },
          cutoutPercentage: 75,
          title: {
            display: false,
            position: 'top',
            fontStyle: 'bold',
            fontSize: 0,
            fullWidth: false,
            padding: 0
          },
          legend: {
            display: false,
            position: 'top',
            fullWidth: false,
            labels: {
              display: false,
              usePointStyle: true,
              fontSize: 15,
              fontStyle: 'bold'
            }
          }
        }
      });
      this.cc++;
    }
  }
```

**Problem is after the loop ended, all canvas id become canvas5 (last count).**
Is there a way to assign so it becomes canvas1, canvas2, canvas3 etc. without just assigning the last count? 
*Note* I cant assign the id from html because of nested loops hence I'm finding a way to bind thx.

Comment: Before `this.chart = new Chart(...` create a variable `const _cc = this.cc` and use it when in the constructor of the `Chart`.

Comment: @Zhared Have you tried using local variable for cc, instead of making it global variable? Also in template file you can add cc field with ngFor index.

Comment: I'll try using local variables. I don't wanna count straight from 1 to 10 but when outer loop is 1, inner goes 1,2 when outer is 2, inner goes 3,4. canvas is in innerloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your charts into an array and you can do something similar to this.

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let chartsArray; let cc = index;" class="px-0 col">
  <canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas{{cc}}" class="canvas-size"></canvas>
```

Comment: I cant use cc=index because its in a nested loop.
something like 
<div *ngFor="let li of testing; let j = index">
     <div *ngFor="let li of testingli; let j = index">
<canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas{{cc}}" class="canvas-size"></canvas>
     </div>
</div>
and it goes like when parent loop is at 1, i need to count 1,2. when parent loop is at 2, i need to count 3,4. I don't wanna count straight from 1 to 10 etc. Its hard to describe but i cant do that way.

Comment: is this you are looking for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556286/generate-the-cumulative-index-within-a-nested-ngfor

Comment: Yes, it's very close to what i mentioned. I'm going to take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! Happy coding!